# java.rmi.MarshalException: ciphering

Tags: java, exception, rmi

i get this error when i try to call a remote interface:

```
java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is:    java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.crypto.Cipher
```

These are the interfaces:

```
public interface Operacion extends Remote{

 String operacionDesencripta(byte ciphertext[],Key key,Cipher cipher)
        throws RemoteException;
```

}

and i call it like this:

```
rmiServidor.operacionDesencripta(ciphertext,key,cipher);
```

After processing all that data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the question exactly?  The error is pretty clear -- you cannot serialize the [`Cipher`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) type.  If you check out the Javadoc for this type, it will tell you:

> In order to create a Cipher object, the application calls the Cipher's
>   getInstance method, and passes the name of the requested
>   transformation to it. Optionally, the name of a provider may be
>   specified.

So instead of passing the `Cipher` directly, you could pass a transformation string instead (`String` is serializable and thus "remotable").

Comment: Thx i got it i just created the cyber instance in both ways and just send the array of bytes and the key :)